# Software to annotate PDF from Excel or Python

Tags: python, pdf, microsoft-excel, pdf-editor

I have a large PDF files. Each PDF page contains a chart and also includes a unique identifier, i.e. chart number.

I have individual comments for each chart and would like to insert these in the corresponding PDF page, e.g. comment for chart 34 goes in PDF page containing chart 34. My current approach is to insert these comments manually, one by one, using the comment tool in Adobe Acrobat Pro.

Is there a way to speed up this process? Ideally, I can write all comments in a spreadsheet (and less ideal, Python) with the chart code next to it. Then, comments would be written to the PDF.

Any ideas?